# c++ binary search with array of char arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, char, compare, binary-search

binary search is sorta working if it finds the value it will correctly return the pos at which the value was found at in array the issue is its only looping through first half of array its never hitting the else statement to increase the start index and always hits the if statement regardless of if the searchingFor word is before or after alphabetically. the players array list has been sorted alphabetically. Any help would be amazing :)

```
            cout << "type name youd like to search for" << endl;
            char playerChoice[10] = "len";
            databaseFunctions.SelectionSort(databaseFunctions.players, databaseFunctions.size);

            int result = databaseFunctions.BinarySearch(databaseFunctions.players, 0, databaseFunctions.size, playerChoice);
```

```
int DataBaseFunctions::BinarySearch(Player* players, int start_index, int end_index, char searchingFor[])
{
    while (start_index <= end_index)
    {
        int middlePoint = (start_index + end_index) / 2;

        if (strcmp(players[middlePoint].playerName, searchingFor) == 0)
            return middlePoint;

        if (searchingFor < players[middlePoint].playerName)
            end_index = middlePoint - 1;

        else
            start_index = middlePoint + 1; // need to fix thiss never hitting else regardless always just -1 instead of adding 1
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It seems like you are comparing pointers when you want to compare strings.

Comment: `if (searchingFor < players[middlePoint].playerName)` --> you cannot compare `char*`s like this. Instead, use `if (std::string(searchingFor) < std::string(players[middlePoint].playerName))`

Comment: gupta u champion <3 thanks so much